# lme4 - Cannot get emmeans when have a nested factor?

Tags: lme4, emmeans

So I have a treatment with 3 factors (Air Temperature, Water Temperature, and Region), but within each Region, there are populations, that work as replicates, e.g., Region A has 4 populations (Poulation 1 to 4), Region B has another 4 populations (Population 5 to 8).
So My model currently is like this:
Model <- lmer(Growth ~ Air + Water + (1|Region/Population) )
Assuming here that ?m saying there's an additive effect between Air+Water+Region , but that Region has a nested random factor called Population .
Problem is, when I check for pairwise comparison:
emmeans(Model, pairwise~Air*Water*Region, , adjust = "tukey")
I get:
No variable named Region in the reference grid.

BUT
If I define my models like this:
Model <- lmer(Growth ~ Air + Water + Region + (1|Population) )
The same emmeans line goes well and gives me the comparisons that I want....but this later model does not have Populations as nested within Region...right?

So how to I get pairwise comparisons if I have a factor with a nested random variable within?

Thank you!